# how to properly implement org.jivesoftware.smack.ConnectionListener

Tags: android, xmpp, google-cloud-messaging

I am developing a GCM Cloud Connection Server (XMPP). I am using the suggested Smack API 4.0.6 library.

How should I implement each method defined by `org.jivesoftware.smack.ConnectionListener`

```
void    authenticated(XMPPConnection connection)
void    connected(XMPPConnection connection)
void        connectionClosed()
void    connectionClosedOnError(Exception e)
void    reconnectingIn(int seconds)
void    reconnectionFailed(Exception e)
void    reconnectionSuccessful()
```

The only examples I can find simply log out messages.

Whats the correct way to reconnect "cleanly" when my server looses its upstream connection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Smack automatically tries to reconnect when it looses connection to your XMPP server.**

Therefore, you are **NOT** required to implement all those methods, you can *override* some of them to extend their functionality.

Comment: I had seen that behaviour with reconnectingIn being called repeatedly, and never successfully reconnecting. can you rely on the Smack implementation to keep the connection open?

Comment: Well, I actually rely on it and it works well even when switching from WiFi to 3G network and vice versa.